# Ограничивает вывод атрибутов в виджете WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

На странице https://v-est.ru/napolnye-pokrytiya/kovrovaya-plitka/ есть фильтр по цвету. Там находится всего 3 элемента. Как только мы выбираем любой из цветов (https://v-est.ru/napolnye-pokrytiya/kovrovaya-plitka/?filter_tsvet=korichnevyi&query_type_tsvet=or), страница перезагружается и в фильтре появляются все цвета. С чем это связано? Кто с таким сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

Если виджет настроен правильно и нет дополнительных плагинов, то должно работать корректно.
У меня тип запроса **ИЛИ**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираются те и отображаются, что заданы.

Результат корректного запроса:

`вашсайт/?query_type_color=or&filter_color=bordeaux,cornflower`

Зашёл к Вам на сайт, вроде всё корректно отображается.
Вот результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Временно и некорректно решил проблему. При заходе на страницу без GET-запросов в глобальном запросе аргумент "product_type" хранит значение "grouped", а при заходе с GET-запросом (имеется ввиду, когда выбрали цвет) аргумент меняет значение на "simple".

Comment: А товар то у Вас какой? Группировка или вариативный? Есть ли плагины для "расширения функционала" woocommerce. Отключить и проверить.